# Finding store selling SM-PD64 reflectors for the Shimano Saint PD-MX80 flat pedals?

Tags: shopping

I've bought the Shimano Saint PD-MX80 flat pedals. According to the user's manual, an optional reflector set is available for them. In [Shimano's dealer's manual](http://si.shimano.com/content/si/pedal/english/PD-MX80/_jcr_content/headerpar/sidownload_0/file.res/C%3a%5Cfakepath%5CDM-PD0001-00-ENG.pdf) one can read that the reflector set is called SM-PD64 ([according service instructions](http://si.shimano.com/content/si/pedal/english/Reflector/_jcr_content/par/sidownload/file.res/SI-PD64A-000-00_ENG.pdf)). However, I didn't succeed finding a store selling them (I could not find it neither on ebay, amazon, froogle nor several bike shops I know).

Does anyone has some suggestions on finding stuff which is obviously sold not so often (preferrably a store shipping to Germany)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by andy256 in a comment, several shops are selling them now in 2017 (also in Germany).

I ordered them in 
https://www.bike-discount.de/de/kaufen/shimano-reflektorset-sm-pd64-fuer-pd-mx80-487758
(where I saw them accidentally while searching for something else) for just 6.49 Euro.

So finally after 4.5 years I have proper reflectors instead of using reflective tape :)

Answer (score 6):

I have no experience with reflectors but I do have experience with ordering "bit parts" from Shimano so may be able to help.

The first step was to go to the Shimano site and find the official distributors for my country (UK). I was quite surprised since I'd never heard of them, but fortunately they had a website etc. (So if you have no joy with the German distributor, you may wish to try the UK distributor).

When I contacted them, these people were happy enough to order the stuff for me, but (a) relatively-speaking they were very expensive, and (b) they took an age to arrive - it was like the distributor had to order them from Japan.

If I tell you that what I had was some SL cleats, and all I wanted was something as simple as some replacement screws (this was when I first started riding, one of mine fell out one day so I figured it would be sensible to get some spares). With hindsight I should have just bought some new cleats, which of course I ended up doing anyway eventually.

Its as few years ago but I can have a look through my old emails and find out exactly who I ordered off, if you can't find this on the Shimano site. Let me know if you'd like me to do this.

Hope this helps some.

Comment: The site was madison.co.uk but unfortunately at first glance I could not see your reflector's part number.

Answer (score 3):

My searching for those reflectors also ran into a dead end. You may posssibly want to consider using some light reflecting tape cut to the desired shape or even light reflecting paint for that same area. Excellent light reflecting tape like is used by emergency vehicles and road signs is available in many hardware stores as is the light reflecting paint. Either of these alternatives should also save weight. The light reflecting tape is also excellent for use on your helmet.

Comment: It's also worth checking an auto parts store for reflectors that can be adapted.  Or your LBS may have a set of cheap pedals whose reflectors could be adapted.

Comment: For the mean time, I already put some low-end reflecting tape on the pedals (but this particular tape does not appear as very durable to me).

As suggested by PeteH, I will first try to contact some of stores mentioned on the https://www.paul-lange.de site which is the official Shimano distributor for Germany and ask for the prices. If it would be too expensive, I might adapt some other reflectors, try a more durable tape or the reflective paint (the latter is knew to me).

Comment: I actually did this and it's lasted a year so far

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this so I looked up this item in Amazon.co.jp, and it's available but out of stock -- and is being sold by a third party vendor. Once you see it back in stock, you may want to see if they'll ship internationally.

[image: Shimano SM-PD64]

Comment: Several sites in Germany and UK show them in stock. But the question was asked 4 years ago and the user hasn't been seen for 6 months. I think we need some sort of *abandoned question* mechanism.

Comment: @andy256 If you would have posted that as answer, I've would have probably noticed that earlier and would have accepted your answer as answer to the question (I think that I was only notified about answers, not about comments to answers somebody else has given).